# How to make Qt app to not show up in taskbar (X11)

Tags: qt, events, x11, taskbar

I working on an application launcher Qt app which should not show up in the taskbar. It is brought to the front via a hotkey (Alt+Space) and should hide if it looses focus. Sometimes it shows up in the taskbar and I have no clue why. Is this a qt bug?

```
setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint
                | Qt::FramelessWindowHint
                | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint
                | Qt::Tool
                );
```

I guess this has something to do with the events that I have to capture. Compilable source code: [github](https://github.com/ManuelSchneid3r/albert), [zip](https://codeload.github.com/ManuelSchneid3r/albert/zip/master) (Qt5). Screencast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EpB4aCzTLg

*edit:* while making this video I found out, that this happens if another window was activated before showing the app.

Comment: Is the question still relevant?

Comment: Tool windows should have `_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR` atom in the `_NET_WM_STATE` property. Use `xprop` to check. If there is no such atom it's a Qt bug. If there is, and it still shows up in taskbar, it's your WM bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all future readers this was a bug in Qt 5.3